# Browser JavaScript memory leaks

Tags: javascript, browser, memory-leaks

When we load more than 100000 objects to javascript array, the memory in the browser increased up to  1.5GB, after the repetition of this process multiple times, the browser shows "a script is slowing down your browser".
Note: after each repetition, we set all variables to *null* in order to help the GC to free the unused variables, but the memory didn't return to its initial state!

how we can set the browser to decrease the memory to its initial state?

Comment: that's not a memory leak, you are creating 100.000 objects inside an array so the array is very big, as expected

Comment: Do you really need all that data loaded?

Comment: yes, but we set all variables to null at the end of the function. The browser, therefore, decreases the memory but not in the initial state!

Comment: yes we need all this data to show them on a map

Comment: Issue is most likely how you are working with the data. JavaScript does not handle long running loops well.

Comment: *"yes we need all this data to show them on a map"* And you need all that data at once? You can not subset the data?

Comment: We cluster data using Openlayer, then show them on the map. But the problem appears even if we do not process the data! as well as not display it on the map!